# Repetição de itens JQUERY

Tags: jquery, html

Boa tarde pessoal,

Surgiu um problema, havia tirado uma duvida sobre sistema de soma com JQUERY, porém gostaria que vcs analisassem o que há de errado no meu codigo pois ele da erro (NaN) com múltiplas caixas de texto, isso que eu fiz é o que o php gera tipo um  cardápio só que eu não consigo somar os pedidos de forma independente.

Aqui esta o js riddle: https://jsfiddle.net/6mkzzvqz/11/

HTML

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form action="#">
<div class="media-body">
  <div class="menu-tittle">
</div>
  <div class="quantity">

      <div class="pizza-add-sub">
        <input type="text" id="qtdpedidos" class="qtdpedidos" value="0"/>
      </div>

  </div>
  <div id="item1" class="pizza-price"> <span id="pizza" class="pizza">10.00</span>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="quantity">

      <div class="pizza-add-sub">
        <input type="text" id="qtdpedidos" class="qtdpedidos" value="0"/>
      </div>

  </div>
  <div id="item1" class="pizza-price"> <span id="pizza" class="pizza">10.00</span>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="quantity">

      <div class="pizza-add-sub">
        <input type="text" id="qtdpedidos" class="qtdpedidos" value="0"/>
      </div>

  </div>
  <div id="item1" class="pizza-price"> <span id="pizza" class="pizza">10.00</span>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="quantity">

      <div class="pizza-add-sub">
        <input type="text" id="qtdpedidos" class="qtdpedidos" value="0"/>
      </div>

  </div>
  <div id="item1" class="pizza-price"> <span id="pizza" class="pizza">10.00</span>
  </div>
</div>
</form>
<p>Valor do Pedido: R$<span id="resultado" class="resultado">0.00</span></p>
```

JQUERY

```
$(document).ready(function() {

        $(".pizza-add-sub").append('<div class="plus qty-pizza">+</div><div class="mines qty-pizza">-</div>');
        $(".qty-pizza").on("click", function() {

        var $button = $(this);
        var oldValue = $button.parent().find("input").val();
        if ($button.text() == "+") {
          var newVal = parseFloat(oldValue) + 1;
        } else {
          // Don't allow decrementing below zero
             if (oldValue > 0) {
                var newVal = parseFloat(oldValue) - 1;
                } else {
                newVal = 0;
              }
        }
        $button.parent().find("input").val(newVal);
        var v1 = $('#item1 span').text();
        var v2 = Number(document.getElementById("qtdpedidos").value);
        document.getElementById("resultado").innerHTML = parseFloat(v1 * v2).toFixed(2);

     });
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você não deve ter tantos elementos com o mesmo ID, como é o caso de: #qtdpedidos e #item1. Os IDs devem ser únicos, qndo for necessário ter mais elementos com uma identificação em comum, use classes ou atributos.

Depois você pode percorrer com um each, como sugestão, todos os ítens:

```
var valorTotal = 0;
$.each($(".quantity"), function(){
      valorTotal += Number($(this).find(".qtdpedidos").val()) * Number($(this).find(".item span").html())
});
```

//#qntidadepedidos alterado para: .qtdpedidos;

//#item1 alterado para: .item;

Aí tu pode aplicar o valorTotal com a formatação que quiser para o resultado final. #resultado

Só lembrando, tenho certeza que não é o caso, mas o cálculo final deve ser feito no servidor, reverificando o valor dos ítens, caso contrário, usuários mal intencionados poderão alterar o valor na página. (=

Answer (score 0):

tenta transformar o v1 em number também:

```
var v1 = Number($('#item1 span').html());
```

Comment: Então amigo, eu fiz as alterações porém ele continua acusando que não é numero.

Comment: A desculpe: muda o text pra html() espera vou editar

Comment: vê se funciona assim.

Comment: Funciona, porém ele só soma com o primeiro elemento, queria somar todos os elementos de uma vez vc tem alguma sugestão de como poderia ser feito?

Comment: sim, é só você sempre pegar o valor de todos os imputs e fazer o calculo no event change entre os inputs: document.getElementById("id").value